# How to import scripts from another folder?

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I have a script named `main.py` that imports `script1.py` from a dir named `folder`.

This `script1.py` imports another script named `script2.py` that resides in the same `folder` directory.

Here is the code:

**main.py**

```
import folder.script1 as s1

s1.func()
```

**folder/script1.py**

```
import script2 as s2

def func():
    s2.func()
```

**folder/script2.py**

```
def func():
    print('Ciao')
```

When I run `main.py` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\try.py", line 1, in <module>
    import folder.script1 as s1
  File "C:\folder\script1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import script2 as s2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'
```

Is there a nice way to make this work or should I change approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import script2 like that in script1 :

```
import folder.script2 as s2
```

Same as you import it in script2, then in works fine.